# Prevent automatic Session creation

Tags: session, tomcat, vaadin, tomcat9, vaadin14

We are using Vaadin 14 on a Tomcat9.
A session is immediately created in Tomcat as soon as the login page of our app is called up. If a lot of sessions have been created here (e.g. penetration test), the Tomcat takes a very long time to delete them. The CPU load also rises to 100%.
Is it possible to prevent the automatic creation of a session and only create one after the login?

We have reduced the session timeout in Tomcat so that there are not so many open sessions.

Comment: "login page of our app is called up. ", is the login page a Vaadin view?

Comment: Yes. The login page is a Vaadin view. If you try to access any view, the user gets rerouted to the login page

Comment: Vaadin needs a session.  There is no way around it.  You would have to extract your login into e.g. a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use Vaadin (for your Login) and *no* sessions.  Vaadin stores the
state of the UI in the session and there is no way around it:

> A user session begins when a user first makes a request to a Vaadin servlet
> by opening the URL of a particular UI. All server requests belonging to
> a particular UI class are processed by the VaadinServlet class. **When a new
> client connects, it creates a new user session**, represented by an instance of
> VaadinSession. Sessions are tracked using cookies stored in the browser.
>
> ---
>
> https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/application-lifecycle/#application.lifecycle.session

So you have to prevent this and  not send your users directly into the
Vaadin application (first).  In your case you could provide a login form
or some SSO gatekeeper to "protect" your resources.